# im trying to make a blackjack game but I cannot assign my deck digit values(for ex 2D = 2 points)

Tags: python, blackjack

I cant assign my card values without it randomizing. (if I do `if randomcard() == 2D: cardvalue = cardvalue + 2`) and 2D pops up it completley gives me something beside 2 for `cardvalue`.

```
def Convertion():  
    intCardValue = 0
    if RandomCard() == "2D":
        intCardValue = intCardValue+ 2

    if RandomCard() == "3D":
        intCardValue = intCardValue+ 3

    print(RandomCard())
    print(intCardValue)
Convertion()
```

Comment: Why use strings for cards in the first place? Use numbers, which are easier to compare and calculate with, and just convert to strings for I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `RandomCard()` randomly returns a card (number, suit), then the problem lies in calling `RandomCard()` multiple times. What you probably want is to store the value of `RandomCard()` in a variable, then work with it.

```
card = RandomCard()
if card == "2D":
    …
elif card == "3D":
    …

print(card)
```